# What will you do to optimize MySQL performance in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-select

```
$query = "select * from a ...";
if($result = mysql_query($query,$con))
{while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);)
        $arr[0][] = $row;
}
$query = "select * from b ...";
if($result = mysql_query($query,$con))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);)
        $arr[1][] = $row;
}
$query = "select * from c ...";
if($result = mysql_query($query,$con))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);)
        $arr[2][] = $row;
}
```

The 3 queries retrieves multiple rows with different structure,
3 queries need 3 round-trip,
10 queries will need 10 round-trip.

How will you optimize this case?

Comment: What is the structure of each table. Do they have something in common?

Comment: No,totally nothing in common.

Comment: Time to lean, time to clean. -1

Comment: Apart from using a DB handler that abstracts the query/loop code, I wouldn't bother changing it. Three simple queries can often be much faster than a complex way to fetch the data in one query.

Answer (score 1):

Select the columns you actually need instead of select *

Other than that, not much to say without knowing what data you need and how they relate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a UNION:

```
$query = "SELECT 'a' AS tablename, a.* FROM a
UNION
SELECT 'b' AS tablename, b.* FROM b
UNION
SELECT 'c' AS tablename, c.* FROM c";
if($result = mysql_query($query,$con))
{while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);)

switch ($row['tablename']) {
    case "a":
        $arr[0][] = $row;
        break;
    case "b":
$arr[1][] = $row;
        break;
    case "c":
        $arr[2][] = $row;
        break;
}
}
```

pardon my php, it's not my area of expertise :)

Comment: Seems it will work only when column numbers are the same.What if not?